# Websocket connection failing from Firefox extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a Firefox extension which connects to a websocket server and sends a message. I packaged it with `web-ext build`, renamed the `.zip` to a `.xpi`. Last month I installed it in Firefox after setting `xpinstall.signatures.required` to `false` in `about:config`. I added the SSL key to the Firefox certificate manager. It worked for a month. Yesterday there was probably a Firefox update and now the extension is blocked becaue it is not signed. After some research, I found that the regular Firefox has not allowed unsigned extensions for a long time. It makes me wonder what version I had until yesterday; I am working on a Ubuntu 20.04 system I set up 2 months ago.

When the extension is loaded manually with `about:debugging`, the extension works as it did before (websocket creation is successful and a message is sent).

I read online that Firefox Developer edition allows unsigned extensions. But after following the exact same steps, I cannot get the extension to work with a `.xpi` or by temporarily loading the extension. It is the same error in both circumstances:

`Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://localhost:9501/.`

The extension has a manifest and a background script

manifest.json:

```
{
  "description": "weblogging app",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "weblogger",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "browser_logger@example.org",
      "strict_min_version": "50.0"
    }
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "permissions": []
}
```

background.js:

```
var websocketArguments = 'wss://localhost:9501';
var connected = new Boolean(false);
var webSocket;
createWebsocket();

function onError(error)
{
   console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
}

function createWebsocket()
{
   webSocket = new WebSocket(websocketArguments);
   webSocket.onerror = onWebSocketError;
   webSocket.onopen = onWebSocketOpen;
}

function onWebSocketError(event)
{
   console.log("WebSocket error observed:", event);
};

function onWebSocketOpen(event)
{
   console.log("WebSocket open: ", webSocket.readyState);
   webSocket.send("hello there");
   connected = true;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever the reason I could not get the extension to work when unsigned, it was just easier to get it signed.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-CA/developers/